# How do you set events through the UI in Brat?

Tags: brat

I'm trying to use events through the UI, I'm not seeing how to properly use them in the documentation. I'm interested in tagging subject predicate and object and then connecting them (since there can be multiple in each sentence).  In this case, subject, predicate and object can be any string, so I've defined them as entities.

```
[entities]
Subject
Predicate
Object

[events]
SPO Arg1:Subject,Arg2:Predicate,Arg3:Object
```

When I tag a sentence as an SPO I see the error above
"Incomplete: exactly 1 Arg1 argument required for event" along with a few additional errors. What is the correct way to identify an event and the arguments for that event?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.  Select an event, then drag arrows from the event to each of the arguments.